# How do you configure the mail command to read Maildir instead of the default mbox on OpenBSD?

Tags: openbsd

By default the `mail` command on OpenBSD seems to read from `mbox` files. I configured `smtpd` to `... deliver to mbox` and I was able to read newly delivered mail using the `mail` command. I want to switch to the more modern `Maildir` format, however, so I updated `smtpd.conf` to instead have `... deliver to maildir` which resulted in `Maildir` directories appearing in users' homes. I can manually walk the `Maildir` directories and confirm that they properly contain new mail. Unfortunately the `mail` command no longer sees this. I've tried setting the `MAIL` environmental variable from `/var/spool/*` to various permutations of `~/Maildir/` but the `mail` command returns errors like `mail: Maildir/: Is a directory`.

Comment: Use a different mail client, e.g. `mutt` from ports. Or patch `mail` to support maildir, but that would likely be more work.

Comment: @thrig If you're reasonably confident OpenBSD's `mail` does not support Maildir, please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mail(1)` has no support for `Maildir` as of OpenBSD 5.8 and so far there's no indication 5.9 will have support for it either.

I'm not sure if there's a technical reason it's not supported or it's simply a lack of time/interest. The 'new' `smtpd` supports both `mbox` and `Maildir`, but the default configuration is `mbox`.